# What could cause NullPointerException inside Sun's JavaKeyStore.engineStore() method?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, keystore

We have an application that is creating a `KeyStore` programmatically. We create the `KeyStore` in the following manner (sample code, suppressing Exception handling for brevity),

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
ks.load( null, null );
... // Add crypto material here
keystore.store( new FileOutputStream( "keystore.ks" ), "password" );
```

Method `store(OutputStream stream, char[] password)` throws the following exception,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineStore(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineStore(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.KeyStore.store(Unknown Source)
```

The `keystore.ks` file is created in the file system. But when we try to inspect it with `keytool` we get,

```
keytool -list -keystore nms.keystore
keytool error: java.io.EOFException
```

Funny thing is, the same code works perfectly on every other machine that we have tested it. In the actual code, none of the arguments passed to the `store` method are `null`, we have triple-checked that.

Some details about the misbehaved machine,

- CentOS 5.8 32 bits
- Sun's JRE 1.6.0_43

Comment: Is the keystore file empty?

Comment: The good news is this happened to other people( Google told me ), but this seems strange. So all other machines are CentOS 5.8 32 bits with JRE 1.6 ?

Comment: Can you try to read the keystore with the latest JDK?

Comment: Did you copy this keystore file from other system?

Comment: @VivinPaliath There are 2 cases. In the first one the the target file doesn't exists. In the second case the target file exists and it's empty. Both cases are failing.

Comment: @Thilo The keyststore cannot be read with latest JDK.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak No, did not copy the keystore file from other system.

Comment: @Adel Do you have any links of pages where this issue is discussed? The same code is working on CentOS 6.3 and 5.6

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation so far for what was happening is that something in the certificates that were being saved to the Keystore was triggering a NPE inside the method

`sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineStore()`.

The certificates that are being generated are saved in the keystore with their full trust chain. For example, the entry for a certificate `A` would be of the form,

`Cert A alias : Cert A -> Intermediate CA Trust -> Root CA Trust`

The error went away after the whole trust chain was re-created. This is consistent with our previous observations because the chain of trust was the only thing different between the systems that were working and the systems that were not.

I've looked at the source of class `sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore` at both [Grep Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/provider/JavaKeyStore.java#JavaKeyStore.engineStore%28java.io.OutputStream,char%5B%5D%29) and [Java Source Code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/security/provider/JavaKeyStore.java.html) but I'm unable to tell what could be causing the NPE in that code.

In the end we have a solution but we don't actually know the root cause.